# Double integral, positive and negative infinity as bounds

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

[image]

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem, at first I tried substituting a for positive infinity and b for negative infinity but got stuck when I tried to substitute these in after integrating for x.

Comment: Please indicate the steps you took and where you got to before you got stuck. As it stands the integral can not be directly calculated (requires a different coordinate system) so it would be useful if we could review your approach.

Comment: I switched to polar co-ordinates to obtain the double integral over some domain D (which is what I'm stuck on) for r*exp(-r^2). I'm just not sure how making the substitutions to convert to polar co-ordinates effects my initial bounds (a and b)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment I'm assuming you've changed the integral to:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}r\ e^{-r^2}\ dr\ d\theta=2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}r\ e^{-r^2}\ dr$$

To find this integral you can consider the limit of:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}2\pi\int_0^{n}r\ e^{-r^2}\ dr$$

let $u=r^2$ so $du=2r\ dr$

$$=2\pi\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{n}-\frac{1}{2}\ e^{-u}\ du$$

$$=2\pi\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\ e^{-u}\right)_0^{n}$$

$$=2\pi\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{2}e^{-n}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

$$=2\pi\times\frac{1}{2}$$

$$=\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a well-known integral - as it stands now, there is not much hope to integrate in Euclidean coordinates, since $\int e^{-x^2}d x$ has no elementary antiderivative.

But think about possibly switching to a different coordinate system. Is there one which simplifies things?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}dx\overset{x^{2}=u}{=}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-1/2}e^{-u}du=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}
 $$ so $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}dxdy=\pi.$$